# Not valid NCName - XSD Validation error

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, argon

The XSD has this element:

`<xsd:element name = "systemReference" type = "xsd:IDREF"/>`

And the value in my XML is this:

```
<systemReference>Axis Boss Ldn</systemReference>
```

And when the validation is triggered, it gives the error:

> Message: Datatype error: Type:InvalidDatatypeValueException,
>   Message:Value 'Axis Boss Ldn' is not valid NCName

I am not able to figure out what is wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared `systemReference` to be a [`xsd:IDREF`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/datatypes.html#IDREF), which must be a valid **[NCName](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#NT-NCName)**, but NCNames cannot contain spaces.  Remove the spaces, or change the type to something like `xsd:string`.